# How can I fold a Tensor that I unfolded with PyTorch that has overlap?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have a Tensor of size: `torch.Size([1, 63840])` which I then unrolled:

```
inp_unfolded = inp_seq.unfold(1, 160, 80)
```

that gives me a shape of: `torch.Size([1, 797, 160])`

How can I re-`fold` that to get a Tensor of `torch.Size([1, 63840])`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, actually the conditions, given `t.unfold(i, n, s)` are:

- `n >= s` (otherwise step is skipping some original data and we cannot restore it)
- `n + s <= t.shape[i]`

Then we can do it via:

```py
def roll(x, n, s, axis=1):
    return torch.cat((x[0], x[1:][:, n-s:].flatten()), axis)
```

explanation:

`x[0]` is the starting chunk that is always unique at start

`x[1:][:, n-s:]` - then, we take rest of rolls and `n-s` depict how many elements will overlap between rolls so we want to ignore them and take only those from `n-s`

ilustration:

```py
x.unfold(0, 5, 2)
tensor([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.],
        [ 3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.], # 3, 4, 5 are repeated
        [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.], # 5, 6, 7 are repeated...
        [ 7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11.],
        [ 9., 10., 11., 12., 13.],
        [11., 12., 13., 14., 15.],
        [13., 14., 15., 16., 17.]])
```

example:

```py
>> x = torch.arange(1., 18)
>> p = x.unfold(0, 5, 2)
>> roll(p, 5, 2, 0)

tensor([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14.,
        15., 16., 17.])
```

you can also try it with

```py
x = torch.arange(1., 18).reshape(1, 17)
```

and axis 1

Answer (score 3):

For that specific configuration, since `63840` is divisible by `160` and the step size is a multiple of the slice size, you can simply select every second element along that dimension and then [`flatten`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html) the resulting tensor:

```py
inp_unfolded[:, ::2, :].flatten(1, 2)
```

More generally, for `t.unfold(i, n, s)`, if `t.shape[i] % n == 0 and n % s == 0` holds, then you can restore the original tensor via:

```py
index = [slice(None) for __ in t.shape]
index[i] = slice(None, None, n // s)
original = t.unfold(i, n, s)[tuple(index)].flatten(i, i+1)
```

Of course you can also use slice notation, if the dimension `i` is known beforehand. For example `i == 1` as in your example:

```py
original = t.unfold(1, n, s)[:, ::n//s, ...].flatten(1, 2)
```